# Crear 20 numeros aleatorios diferentes

Tags: java, random, math

Estoy tratando de crear 20 números aleatorios diferentes pero por algún motivo me salen 20 números aleatorios iguales alguien sabría como podría hacerlo ?

Tengo que añadir que int aleatorio lo he metido dentro de un método y el bucle esta en otro método diferente haciendo otra función que requiero en dicho sitio. Pero lo pongo aquí todo junto para no tener que colocar todo el codigo.

**adjunto código:**

```
//metodo uno donde extraigo Random
int aleatorio =(int) (Math.random()*99999999);

//metodo Dos entre mas codigo donde me resulta mas util usar el bucle
int[] texto = new int[20];
              for (int i = 0; i < texto.length; i++) {
                 texto[i] = aleatorio;
                 system.out.println(texto[i]);
              }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El que genera los numeros aleatorios debe ir dentro del bucle

```
    int[] texto = new int[20];
      for (int i = 0; i < texto.length; i++) {
        int aleatorio =(int) (Math.random()*99999999);
         texto[i] = aleatorio;
         System.out.println(texto[i]);
      }
```

Pero no verifica si ya existe puede que ya exista ese numero

```
int[] texto = new int[20];
      for (int i = 0; i < texto.length; i++) {
        int aleatorio =(int) (Math.random()*99999999);
        if(verificar(aleatorio,texto)){
            //Elnumero ya esta en la lista no contara y se genera otro distinto
            System.out.println("El numero: "+aleatorio+" ya existe en la lista");
            i--;
        }else{
             texto[i] = aleatorio;
             System.out.println(texto[i]);  
        }
      }
```

Debes agregar este metodo para verificar que existe el numero

```
public static boolean verificar(int numero,int[]lista){
    for(int i=0;i<lista.length;i++){
        if(lista[i]==numero)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!!!! Justo era así al tenerlo en 2 metodos diferentes y muchisimo codigo no lograba verlo! He invocado el metodo de aleatorio justo donde me has dicho que iba y ya me funciona correctamente